# VueJs v-bind different class/style from data object with multiple values (possibly from a switch statement)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Not very familiar with Vue and javascript framework in general. I am reading https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html and I am trying to implement something along the lines of following:

```
<div v-for="user in users"
  v-bind:key="user.id"
  v-bind:class="{switch(user.health) {
                   case 'full': return 'green';
                   case 'half': return 'yellow';
                   case 'low': return 'red';
                   default: return 'gray';
                }}">
{{user.name}}
</div>
```

I want to map to a different css class based on `user.health`, but all I've seen from the doc is simple tenary operators. Is there a solve for more complex mapping using switch like above? Or am I completely doing it wrong?

Comment: Tony's answer is, I believe, the best practice for such use case: keep the binded attribute as simple as possible and move any logic to a method or a computed property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will be best to do this

```js
<div v-for="user in users"
  v-bind:key="user.id"
  v-bind:class="getCSSClassBasedOnUserHealth(user)"
{{user.name}}
</div>

methods: {
  getCSSClassBasedOnUserHealth(user) {
    switch(user.health) {
      case 'full':
        return 'green';
      case 'half':
        return 'yellow';
      case 'low':
        return 'red';
      default:
        return 'gray';
    }
  }
}
```